What is the internal data bus?
I've started reading about the 6502.
In this PDF here, what are the internal data bus and internal address bus used for?
Are they used to move data between the internal CPU components? or move data between the CPU and the other system devices?

The internal data bus supports the transfer of data between any two components connected to it.  For example, to increment the PC, the PC values are sent to the ALU with the command to increment the value, then that incremented value is sent back to the PC.  Since main memory is also connected to the internal data bus (via data bus buffer and instruction register), data can be read from (or written to) main memory.  The internal address busses form two halves of the "external" address bus, shared with main memory to do transfers.

The cool thing about 8-bit CPUs was not how powerful their instruction set was but that they fit entirely within a single chip, a first for that era, which made them simple to use (one chip CPU) and fast, since so many operations happen entirely on chip. But by the time the single chip CPU was first developed, programs had already exceeded the need for more than 256 addressable items of RAM (all that is addressable with 8 bits is 256 things). So even 8-bit CPU's needed to have something like 16-bit address busses to access more RAM. Hence the split of address bus into two 8-bit halves.

Man been about a million years since I wrote assembly code for a 6502.  Let me grab my old Ohio Scientific manuals from the days of yore box.

The Markdown processor is mangling the URL by turning ~ into %7e This is it: https://www.princeton.edu/~mae412/HANDOUTS/Datasheets/6502.pdf

Fixed it by using an <a> tag directly.

Sorry for that problem, I see @JeremyP fixed it.

From your PDF, the diagram labelled SY6500 Internal Architecture pretty much nails it. Everything on that diagram is inside the CPU. The arrows labelled AB0 - AB15, D0 - D7 are wires that lead to the chips address and data pins respectively.

Are they used to move data between the internal CPU components?

Yes and no. The internal data bus is used to move data between the components shown to its left and the processor status register to its right. These are all components on the chip. The two address buses (ADL, ADH) are used to move data (data that represents addresses) from internal components to the external address bus.

Thank you.
Is the internal data bus also used to transfer data to the system data bus?

@RoeeToledano, yes, though via the Data Bus Buffer (register) and via the Instruction Register, since those are all that are connected to the external data bus.  In other words, transfers to external data bus take an extra step to go through one of those two registers.
